# How to write Jasmine test to cover event.target.click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I would like to write a Jasmine test spec for my below method.

My Component Method

```
methodName(event): void {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.target.click();
}
```

This is what i have written but don't know what should i write to cover event.target.click

```
it('should prevent default', () => {
   const event = jasmine.createSpyObj('event', ['preventDefault']);
   component.methodName(event);
   expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below, and it worked, but i think there should be a way to use 'createSpyObj' as well for my use case

```
const event = { preventDefault: jasmine.createSpy(), target: { click: jasmine.createSpy() }};
```